# Algebra textbook recommandation for person already familiar with algebra

Tags: book-recommendation

Can you guys please recommend me a good textbook on algebra, given that I am already familiar with lots of algebra stuff and I want to revisit, and deepen my knowledge?

(Little backstory: I started masters program at my uni. Up until now, I always learnt only necessary minimum to pass the exams, but recently I really got into algebra. I had courses on modern algebra, algebraic number theory, algebraic geometry, commutative algebra, etc. I am familiar with all that stuff, but I dont htink I have understanding deep enough. In particular, there is huge difference for me to understand the proof and come up with my own.
Anyway, what would be the good book for me? I started Dummit and Foote, but it seems more suitable to a complete newcomer.)

Many thanks for any input.

Comment: You might want to look at Lang's Algebra, which is a graduate algebra textbook that covers quite a large number of topics.

Comment: I've heard good things about Nathan Jacobson's two-volume *Basic Algebra* (now cheap from Dover), as well as Knapp's two-volume series.